# Jquery: Get next element from an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get the target  from the  with td rowspan=4

Not sure about:

```
$("#fromTd").parent("tr").next().eq($("#fromTd").attr("rowspan")-1)


<table>
   <tr>...</tr>
   <tr>...</tr>
   <tr><td id="fromTd" rowspan="4"></td></tr>
   <tr>...</tr>
   <tr>...</tr>
   <tr>...</tr>
   <tr>...</tr> -> target (can be aleatory position..)
</table>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase?  That code doesn't make sense... can you make your goal clearer?

Comment: @mway, I think he wants to move *to* or target an arbitrary sibling element given a starting position.

Comment: Are you clicking on a `tr` or a `td`? `.next()` will select the next sibling element.

Comment: @David - They don't seem to be siblings. The `td` with `rowspan="4"` is a single child... no siblings.

Comment: You're right, I spotted the nested td after I posted the comment. I stand corrected, sir =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but it sounds like what you want is to get the next `<tr>` after X rows where X is the rowspan of a given `<td>` - 1.  In other words, you want the next row into which that `<td>` will NOT extend.

If that is the case, this should do the trick:

```
var eq = $("#fromTd").attr("rowspan") - 1;
var row = $("#fromTd").parent("tr").nextAll(':eq(' + eq + ')');
```

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wLPA9/

Comment: Just a matter of preference, but I find this slightly more readable: `$("#fromTd").parent("tr").nextAll().eq(eq);`

Comment: It definitely is more readable :)  I'm not sure if it offers any tangible benefits, but I was going for using fewer selectors.  Like you said, just a matter of preference.

Comment: `:eq(n)` is executed as `.eq(n)` in the newest jQuery version (or will be in  >1.4.2) [according to John Resig](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/f1f6bc3ec43d86f5b2a0c2b8bf711a2d35930717#commitcomment-157856). So you might as well save jQuery a step and avoid the `":eq(" + n + ")"` string concatenation and verbosity by using `.eq(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do what that line looks like it's trying to do—selecting the row after the end of the current cell's `rowspan`—you would just need [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of `next()`, which only ever returns the immediate next element sibling.

```
var td= $('#fromTd');
var nextr= td.parent().nextAll().eq(td.attr('rowspan')-1);
```

Alternatively if you've got lots of following rows and you don't want to have to select them all to pick a single one out, you could do it slightly more efficiently with the standard DOM `rows` and `rowIndex` properties:

```
var nextr= td.closest('table')[0].rows[td[0].parentNode.rowIndex+td[0].rowSpan];
```